# Restrict bottom sheet swipe down

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have created an activity with bottom sheet behavior.  I am sharing the layout XML here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/video_details_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/player_sheet_peek_height"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainMediaFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/zero_dimen"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoPlayerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:resize_mode="fit"
            app:surface_type="texture_view" />


    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/videoScroller"
        style="@style/scrollBarStyle"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/zero_dimen"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!--todo:include scroll view content layout-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After the implementation, I can collapse the bottom sheet by touch and drag any of the views in this layout. But, I want to close the sheet by dragging video view (mainMediaFrame) in the layout. That is, I don't want to dismiss the bottom sheet by scrolling down the nested scroll view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class ScrollTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mVideoDetailsView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            activityLockBehavior.setAllowUserDragging(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mVideoDetailsView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            activityLockBehavior.setAllowUserDragging(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mVideoDetailsView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            activityLockBehavior.setAllowUserDragging(true);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Added this scroll listener to nested scrollview

```
mNestedScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new ScrollTouchListener());
```

Answer (score 3):

Below solution will not drag bottomsheet if user is touching `VideoView`.

Concept is simple

- Disable touch of VideoView
- Disable dragging when user touched VideoView

In your Activity

```
final LockBottomSheetBehaviour behavior = (LockBottomSheetBehaviour) LockBottomSheetBehaviour.from(bottomSheet);
findViewById(R.id.videoView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                behavior.setAllowUserDragging(false);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                behavior.setAllowUserDragging(true);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

In layout replace

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

to

```
app:layout_behavior="com.package.LockBottomSheetBehaviour"
```

**LockBottomSheetBehaviour.class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class LockBottomSheetBehaviour<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> {
    private boolean mAllowUserDragging = true;

    public LockBottomSheetBehaviour() {
        super();
    }

    public LockBottomSheetBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setAllowUserDragging(boolean allowUserDragging) {
        mAllowUserDragging = allowUserDragging;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!mAllowUserDragging) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage setDraggable(true) and setDraggable(false) on onState method when STATE_COLLAPSE and STATE_EXPANDED

```
LinearLayout contentLayout = findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
    sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(contentLayout);
    sheetBehavior.setDraggable(false);
```